# bashrc add command but do not execute

Tags: bash, bashrc

I have a folder in `~` called `work` that contains all my work. Usually when I start an instance of Terminal I type `cd work`.

I would like to avoid this because it's very repetitive. I tried putting `cd work` in my `.bashrc` but I realized that I don't always want to `cd work` - for instance, when I `Open Terminal here` or when I open a Terminal in VSCode (which should open my Terminal in the current project directory, not `work`).

My idea is having the Terminal type out `cd work` whenever I open it, but not actually execute the command. If I really need to `cd work`, all I have to do is hit Return. However, if I don't want to do that, I can just `Ctrl+C`.

Is doing this possible?

Comment: This was asked before [How to start a terminal with certain text already input on the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5363/how-to-start-a-terminal-with-certain-text-already-input-on-the-command-line) however there are some alternative solutions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391679/how-to-automatically-insert-a-string-after-the-prompt) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82630/put-text-in-the-bash-command-line-buffer)

Comment: Read `man bash`, the "INVOCATION" section. You can probably `[[ -n "$PS1" ]] && cd work`, by why not type the 8 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

You can use the bash built-in command [`read`](https://linuxhint.com/bash_read_command/):

- Either use it in a simple one line and add it to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file like so:

  ```
  read -p "${PS1@P}cd work"; cd work
  ```
- Or define a custom function and call it at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file like so:

  ```
  myfunction() {
      mycommand="cd work"
      read -p "${PS1@P}$mycommand"
      $mycommand
  }

  myfunction
  ```

#### Information

- `read -p` will show the text and wait for either <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to abort.
- `${PS1@P}` will show your current prompt before the text.

Comment: Hmmm this comes really close. It works, but when I open a new Terminal I kinda get the text waiting for me there, without starting bash itself. Bash starts after I either press Return or Ctrl+c. Regardless, if this question doesn't get more answers, I will mark this as accepted.

Comment: @a3y3 It runs in bash!... Bash already in use when you see the text. Also "If I really need to cd work, all I have to do is hit Return. However, if I don't want to do that, I can just Ctrl+C."... You got what you asked for :)

Comment: @a3y3 I updated the answer to show the prompt as well.