# How to launch a terminal from script and another script to run in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

I run a script when I log in that basically looks like this:

```
chromium-browser &
xchat &
cd ~/randomdir && gnome-terminal &
qbittorrent &
```

On the third line (`cd ~/randomdir && gnome-terminal &`), I would like to run another script in the terminal that I'm opening up. How can I do that in this script?

Comment: you might looking for http://askubuntu.com/questions/3359/with-a-launcher-for-a-terminal-application-how-can-i-keep-the-terminal-open-aft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run a non-interactive shell that runs your script and then replaces itself with an interactive bash shell.

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory="$HOME/randomdir" -x bash -c './randomscript; exec bash' &
```

Answer (score 3):

`gnome-terminal --working-directory=randomdir`

Is this what you are looking for?

By the way, `man gnome-terminal` should help :)

EDIT:

However, if you want to keep the terminal open you can do this:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=randomdir -e COMMAND #launch the command - terminal will close
gnome-terminal --working-directory=randomdir #open a new terminal with the same default path
```

These 2 commands added in your script.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, I want to launch another script in the newly opened terminal, and keep the terminal open after that  script exits.

Comment: from the OP "By the way I tried `cd ~/rockbox && gnome-terminal -e "./randomscript.sh"&` and that opened the script, but closed the terminal after the script exited."

Comment: This works, but I like the other answer better because it keeps the same window, and the other commands in the file still run with their solution.(I couldn't get your's to do that, even with adding the &'s at the end of lines.)

Comment: I got it to run like I wanted it to by `gnome-terminal --working-directory=randomdir -e ./randomscript.sh && gnome-terminal --working-directory=randomscript&`