# How can I feed clipboard content to gnome-terminal?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, clipboard, xclip

I have a plugin that generates and copies to the clipboard a ready-to-paste command. For now I open a new terminal, paste the command and execute it.
I want to write a script that automatically opens a new terminal and runs that command using the clipboard as input.

I tried to use xclip but can't figure out how to pipe its output to gnome-terminal, and all of the threads I saw focus on the opposite problem: saving command output to clipboard which is NOT what I want to do.

What I tried: `xclip -se c -o | gnome-terminal -e`

It says "Failed to parse arguments: Missing argument for -e". So at the very least I have a syntax problem.

I have a feeling that I might not be approaching this problem the right way. Complete noob here, so the more details the better!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you give `… | gnome-terminal -e -` a try?

Comment: I thought this would be easy. The best I have gotten so far is `gnome-terminal -e  "$(xclip -sel c -o)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `gnome-terminal` can't take input from stdin, so you have to use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
gnome-terminal -e "$(xclip -se c -o)"
```

Also, if you want to perform word splitting and globbing on the clipboard contents before it's run, you can use this:

```
gnome-terminal -x $(xclip -se c -o)
```

---

If you need to hold the terminal open when the command completes, you could use this:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "$(xclip -se c -o); read -p 'Press Enter to close.'"
```

Or if you want to go to an interactive prompt:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "$(xclip -se c -o); bash"
```

For more ideas, see [With a launcher for a terminal application, how can I keep the terminal open after the program is complete?](https://askubuntu.com/q/3359/301745)

Comment: Note that gnome-terminal closes instantly once command you run exits, so one would have to spaw  extra shell if one wants to keep gnome-terminal open and interactive

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Oh yeah, I forgot I have mine set to stay open when the process exits. I would solve that with `gnome-terminal -x bash -c "$(xclip -s c -o); read -p 'Press Enter to close.'"`

Comment: OP, let me know if this works for you, since the details may change depending on what command you want to run, and how you want to run it.

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea, it works perfectly! For now I'm using     gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=PROFILENAME --working-directory="/PATH/" -x bash -c "$(xclip -s c -o); bash" to keep the command prompt active, I might also use your very convenient     read -p 'Press Enter to close.'

Comment: Sorry I just saw that I can't edit after 5 minutes... So `gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=PROFILENAME --working-directory="/PATH/" -x bash -c "$(xclip -s c -o); bash"` is fine for now, but I originally setup that specific profile to not close after command exits. However it displays a yellow header "The child process exited normally with status 0." that masks the first lines of output. I switched it back to closing after command exits and I'm using your `; read -p 'Press Enter to close.'` which is more elegant and suited to my needs considering the command I'm running.

Comment: @MonkeyBack OK, great! I'll add that to the answer, then. BTW, you should be able to scroll up to see the output covered by the yellow header.

Comment: @MonkeyBack Also, while testing, I noticed that `xclip -s` is not the same as `xclip -selection`. It seems to always get the contents of the `primary` selection, regardless of what argument you give it.

Comment: @wjandrea Oh nice catch! I was wondering why the command `gnome-terminal -x bash -c "$(xclip -se c -o); read -p 'Press Enter to close.'"` was working fine when entered from a terminal, but did not work when executed from a script. Changing it to `gnome-terminal -x bash -c "$(xclip -selection clipboard -o); read -p 'Press Enter to close.'"` solved it so thanks again!
Edit: `xclip -se c -o` also works fine from the script.